# Troubleshooting adding Cocoa pods

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa, console

this is the error message I receive when attempting to run the application after installing the pod file to the project, I have tried to uninstall/reinstall the pods from the project, update the pods, and set the build location to custom "relative to project" nothing works. Below is the message I receive in the console.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/omaraleisa/Desktop/Chat-iOS11-master/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChameleonFramework' ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/omaraleisa/Desktop/Chat-iOS11-master/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/omaraleisa/Desktop/Chat-iOS11-master/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/omaraleisa/Desktop/Chat-iOS11-master/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SVProgressHUD'
>   ld: framework not found ChameleonFramework

Comment: Please add screenshots of 1. Project root folder 2. Podfile 3. Terminal command you entered 4. Xcode project navigator

Comment: Delete your Derived Data folder and clean your project

Comment: it worked got it thanks